# How do I filter names containing "_" in object window in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

For example. I have a lot of objects names "C_something" how do I filter objects in the objects window to only show the ones starting with "C_" since "_" is used as a wildcard character.

[image of IDE GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgNBb.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape underscore in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199531/escape-underscore-in-pl-sql)