# How to use single character instead of wildcard

Tags: sql, oracle

i can't find solution on internet of that problem, everything what i got is connected with wildcard, and i don't wanna to use wildcard in my case

i want to find all tables that have ending '_N' so im trying to execute something like that

```
select * from dba_tables v
where v.table_name like '%_N';
```

but '*' wildcard means that search all tables with name [can be everything][need to be some character]N i just want to use that '*' i want to have all tables with '_N' ending, so for example tables like 'EXAMPLE_N' 'HELP_ME_N'.

How can i not use '_' wildcard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape underscore in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199531/escape-underscore-in-pl-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21380261/1132334

Comment: sorry you were right, i was trying "how to not use wildcards" etc. and only result i had was threads about wildcards. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `escape`:

```
where v.table_name like '%$_N' escape $
```

The default escape character is `\`:

```
where v.table_name like '%\_N';
```

That works as well.

Comment: Don't know, but I'd guess because answers to obvious dupes are often punished ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You could escape `'_'` using `\`

```
select * from table  
where table_name.column_name like '%\_N';
```

Comment: Don't know, but I'd guess because answers to obvious dupes are often punished ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this:

```
select * from dba_tables v
where regexp_like(v.table_name,'.*_N$');
```